# Launch Local Executable File Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla, executable-jar

All,

I have written a desktop java program that will capture user audio and am looking to use it in an add on for Mozilla. I am not too familiar with JavaScript or creating ad ons for Mozilla, but know enough that the add on will need to be created using primarily JavaScript.

What I know in my limited use of JavaScript is that you cannot access user local files.

**Is there any way to use JavaScript and the Mozilla Add On Builder to issue a command like I do in the system console of -jar filepath parameters, which launches the jar file?**

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to find `java.exe` file and run it with some arguments like it's shown in this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess#See_also).
You can use example from [Addon Sdk Docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/modules/sdk/system/environment.html) to check `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` variables and try to find `java.exe` there.

I don't know if it will work, but is only my idea.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/Community-developed-modules

This page points to a "subprocess" module for the AddonSDK that will help you launch external processes.